# Windows 10 - Hyper-V Support : Yes, Virtualization: Disabled

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualization, docker, hardware-virtualization

I've gone through all the steps and gotten Hyper-V enabled properly, but my system still shows Virtualization as disabled even though it also shows Hyper-V is enabled.  I have enabled Hyper-V in Windows Features, and checked my BIOS but there are no options related to virtualization, which worries me that it may not be supported, but it also says that Hyper-V is supported so I'm a little confused.

All the results I'm finding on Google are how to enable Hyper-V, as if enabling it should also enable virtualization, but this isn't the case for me.  How do I get this enabled?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows 10?  If you run "systeminfo" from a command prompt, what do the last 4 lines show you?  Does it say "A hypervisor has been detected" or do you see these 4 lines: VM Montior Mode, Virtualization enabled, Second Level address translation, and Data Execution available?  Do the 4 lines all say yes?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not so sure that's the case.  The only security software I'm running is (fully updated) Windows Defender.  It's Windows so I just assume it's broken and compromised, I keep it isolated from the rest of my network.  I'm not able to check the full names of the virtual adapters now, I'll update them as you've asked when I'm home.

Comment: @Ramhound the names of the switches are Docker NAT, New Virtual Switch, and Default Switch.

Answer (score 0):

The tips provided by @essjae helped me figure out that my hardware does not, in fact, support virtualization.

Comment: fyi, i have googled ways to edit firmware with hexeditors, to allow virtualization in BIOS

Comment: @Ramhound and you added that answer 2 hours later.  But do whatever makes you happy.